# Can I make two headers? There is a problem with the type of data(numeric, character)

Tags: r

I need two header.

for example
this is what I want excel file.
but I want to keep all columns as numeric type.

```
a b c
aa bb cc
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I try that
first, I convert all columns to character. (by using as.character)

second, I put the second head (aa,bb,cc) in the first row.

third, I make a df to excel (by using read.csv)

In this case,

All columns are converted to character type. So
There is a problem with the conversion to scientific notation.

Even when I open the file with notepad.

```
a b c
0.001 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0.009
```

the character types, such a problem arises.
but, the numeric type does not have such a problem.

Comment: If you are looking to ultimately create an Excel file then I suggest looking into the openxlsx package. You can write headers and start your data on specific lines. For example, you could write headers on row 1 and row2 and start your data on row3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used " append "

(1) saving xlsx

```
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()

  # create a sheet in the workbook
  openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, 'sheet1')
  # add the data to the new sheet
  openxlsx::writeData(wb,'sheet1', col_df)
  openxlsx::writeData(wb,'sheet1', data_df,
                           startRow = 3,
                           colNames = F)

# saving the workbook
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, './Data/final.xlsx', overwrite=T)
```

(2) saving csv

```
col_df %>% write.table('./Data/final.csv', na="",
                       sep=',',
                       row.names=F,
                       quote=F)

data_df %>%  write.table('./Data/final.csv',
                        sep=',',
                        quote=F,
                        row.names=F,
                        na="",
                        col.names=F,
                        append=T)
```